# Freenas and Active Directory

Tags: samba, active-directory, truenas

I'm trying to setup my Freenas server with Active Directory, it's connected fine and the following works:

```
[root@storage01] /# wbinfo -t
checking the trust secret for domain ISD via RPC calls succeeded

[root@storage01] /# wbinfo -g
*LIST OF GROUPS*

[root@storage01] /# wbinfo -u
*LIST OF USERS*
```

But when I setup a ZFS Dataset and try and setup the permissions to be one of our local active directory groups, no AD groups or users are in the dropdowns.

On top of this I seem to be getting this spammed a lot in the messages so I assume they might be linked:

```
eb 19 16:08:48 storage01 nmbd[65816]: Error - should be sent to WINS server
Feb 19 16:08:48 storage01 nmbd[65816]: [2014/02/19 16:08:48.242463, 0] nmbd/nmbd_incomingrequests.c:172(process_name_refresh_request)
Feb 19 16:08:48 storage01 nmbd[65816]: process_name_refresh_request: unicast name registration request received for name STORAGE01<03> from IP 10.44.15.152 on subnet UNICAST_SUBNET.
Feb 19 16:08:48 storage01 nmbd[65816]: [2014/02/19 16:08:48.242487, 0] nmbd/nmbd_incomingrequests.c:173(process_name_refresh_request)
Feb 19 16:08:48 storage01 nmbd[65816]: Error - should be sent to WINS server
Feb 19 16:08:48 storage01 nmbd[65816]: [2014/02/19 16:08:48.242530, 0] nmbd/nmbd_incomingrequests.c:172(process_name_refresh_request)
```

Any help will really be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

### Set the Rights Manually.

- Click on "shell".
- chown  "domain.local\username":"domain.local\groupname" /mnt/VolName/Sharename
- chmod 777 /mnt/VolName/Sharename